# xmllint isn't working in windows command prompt

Tags: xmllint

I've tried to check xml-file on validness with cmd.exe by using the command 'xmllint' as in the example:
xmllint -schema Bookstore.xsd --noout Bookstore-XSD.xml
but as a result, I saw the error:

***'xmllint' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.***

Should I install some specific library? And if I should, where is it must be (what is the folder)?

Comment: @ggorlen installing the package helped me 7 years ago. Don't use Windows since then :)

Comment: Glad to hear but other people with the same problem might still wind up at this thread (7k views as of now) and should be directed to the canonical dupe to get the most complete answer. The default phrasing makes it seem like a question but it's just a vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmllint` isn't a standard part of Windows. It's typically used on a Unix-based operating system.

You *can* install it via [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) on Windows as part of the [libxml2 package](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.1-1&grep=xmllint). Alternatively, there might be a standalone Windows version of `xmllint.exe` available if you Google for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a standalone Windows executable at the `xmllint` download page at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/xmllint/downloads/list).

Comment: No, that's not the real xmllint program. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16505201/407651.