# xmllint is not recognized in Windows as command

Tags: xml, windows, cygwin, command-prompt

I tried running xmllint in Windows Command Prompt and got the following error:

*‘xmllint’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*

In another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145870/xmllint-isnt-working-in-windows-command-prompt), Matthew Strawbridge advises to install the .exe [from cygwin](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.1-1&grep=xmllint), however it no longer appears to be available.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin now contains a newer version of libxml: 
[2.9.2](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.2-1&grep=xmllint) or [2.9.3](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.3-1&grep=xmllint).