# use xmllint in cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, xmllint

I am using cygwin on a window 8 machine. When I type

```
$ xmllint --format something.xml
```

It says: -bash: xmllint: command not found

How can I use xmllint with cygwin? Is there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Search package

```
cygcheck -p xmllint.exe$
```

Result

```
Found 1 matches for xmllint.exe$
x86_64/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.1-1
```

Then install

```
setup-x86_64 -qP libxml2
```

Comment: the quiet package install command is a lifesaver! Thank you! `setup-x86_64 -qP <package_name>`

Comment: I couldn't install this package via cygwin so used this approach instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16505201/945721

Answer (score 3):

You're better of just installing *all* of CygWin, not just the default packages. Then you don't have to worry about possibly missing programs.

Disk space is cheap, having to waste time figuring out what package contains what programs is not :-)

If you *must* pick and choose, you can search for the executable [here](http://cygwin.com/packages/). Based on a cursory search, it's available in `Libs/libxml2`.

Comment: I found cygwin to be much more enjoyable when I **stopped** installing every package.  The initial install took so long that I avoided installing cygwin all together.  Now, finding and installing cygwin packages doesn't take too long -- unless the package doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @Josiah, I don't have to install Cygwin so often that it's a problem :-) In any case, I've ditched Cygwin for now as I'm using the new Linux subsystem in Win10.